# Notepad++ How to remove last character from selection

Tags: replace, notepad++

For example i have

```
06183,19760201,19891231,16,54.9101,8.3268,Westerland, (Wind),Schleswig-Holstein
06184,19880801,20090615,6,53.5333,8.1667,Wilhelmshaven, (Flugplatz),Niedersachsen
06186,20000401,20190527,268,50.1989,7.8651,Nastätten,Rheinland-Pfalz
```

I search with `^(?:.+?,){8}` to find lines with 8 `,`

When i do this in Notepad++ it select the line all the way to the 8th `,`.

How can i remove this last comma because if i replace now with whitespace the whole selection is replaced.

The result should look like:

```
 06183,19760201,19891231,16,54.9101,8.3268,Westerland (Wind),Schleswig-Holstein
    06184,19880801,20090615,6,53.5333,8.1667,Wilhelmshaven (Flugplatz),Niedersachsen
    06186,20000401,20190527,268,50.1989,7.8651,Nastätten,Rheinland-Pfalz
```

That there is only 1 comma between place and state.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try asking on [su] instead.

Comment: Would a simple find of: `, (` then replace with: ` (` (space and `(`) help? (at least based on the example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to capture all the text **before** the 7<sup>th</sup> comma in a group (so only include 6 commas there), match the 7<sup>th</sup> comma outside that group, and require there is an 8<sup>th</sup> ahead. Then reproduce that group as replacement:

Find what: `^((?:.+,){6}.+),(?=.+,)`
Replace with: `\1`
⦿ Regular expression ☐ . matches newline

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and it keeps the last comma there, no matter how many commas are between the 7th and the last one. Thanks so much!